# How can I convert CharArray / Array<Char> to a String?

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin

I have a `CharArray` whose contents are characters like:

```
val chars = arrayOf('A', 'B', 'C')
```

or

```
val chars = "ABC".toCharArray()
```

I want to get the string `"ABC"` from this. How can I do it?

`chars.toString()` does not work; it works as if `chars` was a normal integer array.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

you can simply using `Array#joinToString`:

```
val result: String = chars.joinToString("");
```

**OR** convert `chars` to `CharArray`:

```
val result: String = String(chars.toCharArray());
```

**OR** declaring a primitive `CharArray` by using `charArrayOf`:

```
val chars = charArrayOf('A', 'B', 'C');
val result: String = String(chars);
```

Comment: ```toCharArray``` Won't work if String contains emojis. 
```"AB✅".toCharArray()``` will print: ```[A, B, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ✅, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `concatToString`.

```
val chars = "ABC".toCharArray()
val result = chars.concatToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, the `String(chars: CharArray)` constructor can be invoked as either

```
    val ctor: (CharArray) -> String = ::String
    val result = chars.let(ctor)
```

or

```
    val result = chars.let { String(it) }
```